# html canvas does not redraw

Tags: html, canvas

I draw varicolored canvas and on click redraw it and draw black rectangles. But rectangles does not remove! What I'm doing wrong?
Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/82nnJ/

```
    function draw_palette() {
        $c = document.getElementById('palette');
        $ctx = $c.getContext('2d');
        var size = 256;
        $ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size); //
        var r = 255;
        var a = 255;
        for (var g = 0; g < size; g++) {
            for (var b = 0; b < size; b++) {
                $ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", " + (a/255) + ")";
                $ctx.fillRect(g, b, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        draw_palette();

        $('#palette').click(function(e) {
            draw_palette();
            var x = e.pageX - $(this).position().left;
            var y = e.pageY - $(this).position().top;
            var radius = 5;
            $ctx.rect(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius+1, 2*radius+1);
            $ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            $ctx.stroke();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be beginPath and closePath methods.

```
$ctx.beginPath();
$ctx.rect(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius+1, 2*radius+1);
$ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
$ctx.stroke();
$ctx.closePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar issue.  I have a chart that was programmed in javascript on the web-side and a server transmitting data to the chart.  Used websockets to update the chart on a realtime basis.

Basically in the onmessage event the Canvas object was destroyed and constructed using the DOM.  With the previous object destroyed this ensures that it repaints correctly.

Here's what I did...

```
    var c = document.getElementsByName("myCanvas")[0];

    if (c != null)
    {
        c.remove();
    }

    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.setAttribute("name", "myCanvas");
    c.setAttribute("width", 900);
    c.setAttribute("height", 600);
    c.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid #d3d3d3");

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



    document.body.append(c);
```